# Tableau, align Dual Axis

Tags: axis, tableau-api, synchronize

This [link](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/windows/en-us/multiplemeasures_dualaxes.html) explains how to create dual axis on tableau so charts look like this

[image]

but when I try to re-create this, all I get is the below. Where do I right click to select "Synchronize Axis"

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag the `[Curve]` pill to the right side of the bar chart. You'll see a black dotted line appear where the axis ought to be. Drop the pill, and a second axis will appear. (Equivalently, right click on either measure on the rows shelf and check Dual Axis.)

Right click on that new axis and click "Synchronize Axis".

Answer (score 2):

In rows where there are two variables in between SUM(Number of Records) and curve Right-click between them you will get one option as Dual Axis .when you will click on that you will get desired result.

[Righclick between Sum(Number of Records) and curve]

Do as describe in image 
[image]